# html5 can't embed youtube video

Tags: html

I'm using Aptana studio 3, and i'm trying to embed a Youtube video. I've watched three Youtube tutorials all showing me the same method. But when I load the web page I get "the file or directory could not be found." where the video should be.

```
<div class ="center">
            <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/JijNVImAGSc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
```

The class "center" is just,

```
.center{
            text-align: center; 
        }
```

I've tried this with multiple videos with the same outcome.

Also i'm getting a warning symbol and it says "iframe proprietary attribute "allowfullscreen". I'm not sure if that helps but I tried to remove that section of code once and it did not help.

Comment: And what is the actually role of "html5" in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change the `src` attribute to `src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JijNVImAGSc"`

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I'd up vote but my reputation is too low.

Answer (score 0):

**YouTube iFrame**

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

**YouTube Embedded**

```
<embed
width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed>
```